# Overlapping screen when opening a question while Achievement is open on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

I just noticed a bug in the Stack Exchange Android app. A question is displayed incorrectly if the Achievements drawer is already open when the app loads a question. It looks like this:

[image: Garbled display screenshot]

To reproduce:

1. Open the Stack Exchange app, and tap the Achievements icon from the top.
2. Leave the app without closing, then try to open a question from external source (e.g. search result, web browser, or Hot Network Question widget)

For reference, I'm running Android 5.1 on a Nexus 5, and the app version is 1.0.68.

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. I plead to reopen this, since it happens that the cause is different than the dupe: the dupe has fixed many issues related to rendering error, but not this particular issue.

Comment: Open a new question if you truly have a separate issue. It will likely get more attention than a reopen vote.